# Suppress breaks in CGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Is there a possibility to suppress the automatic breaks in CGI after i use the p-tag?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header();
print $cgi->start_html();
print $cgi->img({ -src => "http://127.0.0.1/pic2.png", -align => "left" });
print $cgi->p({ -align => "middle" }, "Projekt Zeus");
print $cgi->img({ -src => "http://127.0.0.1/pic1.png", -align => "right" });
print $cgi->end_html();
```

Right now the problem is that the second picture appears in a new row.

Comment: p-tag means paragraph. If you don't want a new paragraph, don't emit the p-tag.

Comment: I'm afraid that perl CGI library makes sense only if you already understand HTML well.

Comment: And most of it doesn't make sense even then :) The HTML output functions are pretty horrible, everyone I know uses a template library instead.

Comment: I find these functions a lot more intuitive than template libraries ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating a `p` element between the two `img` elements. By default, a `p` element is rendered as a block and with some margin above and below. The `align` attributes modify the rendering, but to make the images appear on both sides of the text, change the order so that both `img` elements precede the `p` element, i.e. use the order

```
print $cgi->img({ -src => "http://127.0.0.1/pic2.png", -align => "left" });
print $cgi->img({ -src => "http://127.0.0.1/pic1.png", -align => "right" });
print $cgi->p({ -align => "middle" }, "Projekt Zeus");
```